# how to use deleteMany in transaction of mongoose

Tags: node.js, mongodb, mongoose

I want to delete an array of model schema from collection.

for removing one model I use

```
    let place = await Place.findById(placeId);

    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await place.remove({ session: sess });// remove place
    await sess.commitTransaction();
```

if `place` is a array

```
    let place = await Place.find({title : "Eiffel"}); // Array of Model

    const sess = await mongoose.startSession();
    sess.startTransaction();
    await place.deleteMany({ session: sess });// error ????
    await sess.commitTransaction();
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
await place.deleteMany({'xyz': 999}).session(sess);
```

Comment: thank you for answering but place is a variable that is Array of Model... we had error with your suggestion code...

Comment: `place.forEach(async (p) => {
      p.remove({ session: sess });
    });` worked for me

Answer (score 0):

You could always map the array to create an array of unique id's of them documents, then delete it at such:

```
const idsToDelete = place.map((obj) => obj._id);
await Place.deleteMany({ _id: {$in: [...idsToDelete]} }).session(session);
```

The above utilises the $in operator, to only delete documents where the _id is any of those passed in to {$in: []}. This allows a quick work around to ensure the delete operation is using a transactional session.

Check this out for more info on the $in operator:
https://kb.objectrocket.com/mongo-db/the-mongoose-in-operator-1015